# unwanted height and width of body element occuring

Tags: html, css

In my HTML and CSS code, I have written everything properly.
But in my web page, an unwanted height and width of body is occurring. It's just like my whole container is within 1370 px width and 1773px height,but I get an extra 300px of width and 300px of height .I have checked the padding and margin of all elements and everything is OK but I can't figure out what is wrong......so help me.

Comment: Care to provide some code or a link to an example?

Comment: `HTML` and `CSS` are not gadgets. You shouldn't tag your questions with the latest versions just to let people know your page is up to date with the latest tech. You should only use them when you are asking about features specific to those particular versions. Please retag this with `html` and `css` instead of `html5` and `css3`, after you create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer... the solution of above problem is that we have to use overflow-x : hidden;  and overflow-y : hidden ;  property on  body element.